# Is scheduling an online interview a functional requirement in an agent system?

Tags: agile

I am confused as to whether scheduling an online interview is a functional or a non-functional requirement in an agent system.

Answer (score 1):

Non-functional requirements describe the *operation* of a system rather than it's behaviour.

Examples might be:

- Performance
- Security
- Maintainability
- Backups

Scheduling an online interview is a desired behaviour of the system, hence it is a *functional requirement*.